# MultiSelect with formState issue on form Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I am using `MultiSelect` inside a form and wanted to set the `formState` with the selected values using `onChange`.

At present, the below code passes the default `null` value for `permission_sets` on form submit.

Can someone take a look and let me know how to update the value of `permission_sets`  inside `formState` from `onChange` on dropdown selections. This will pass the actual selected values on the form Submit.

```
const formState = {
  permission_sets: "",
}

function updateFormState(key, value) {
  formState[key] = value;
}

function App() {
  const [permission_sets, set_permission_sets] = useState([]);
  return (
          <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>permission_sets</Form.Label>
          <MultiSelect
           options={[
            { label: "Operations", value: "Operations" },
            { label: "ReadOnlyAccess", value: "ReadOnlyAccess" },
            { label: "Dba", value: "Dba"},
            ]}
           id="permission_sets" 
           labelledBy="Select"
           value={permission_sets}
           onChange={set_permission_sets}    
          />
         </Form.Group>
<Button onClick={validate}>Submit Request</Button>
)}
```

Comment: Please provide the name of the package you are using for `MultiSelect` as well since there might be a misconfiguration in your code that is specific to the package.

Comment: is this react-bootstrap. just FYI onChange should give an event which you read something like `e.target.selectedOptions` . need more clarity on what library you are using.

Comment: @Tung - This is `import { MultiSelect } from "react-multi-select-component";` . I am using react-bootstrap

Comment: I am trying to implement some like `onChange={(e) => updateFormState("permission_sets", e.target.value)}` to set the value for `permission_sets` in `formState` . But not sure how to do it for multiselect.

Comment: looking at the documentation for `react-multi-select-component`, I'm pretty sure that their `onChange` has the structure like this `(selectedValue) => {}`. So to transform it to `onChange={(e) => updateFormState("permission_sets", e.target.value)}`, you'll get something like this `onChange={(selectedValue) => updateFormState("permission_sets", selectedValue)}`. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Tung - I tried doing that, but it didn't work. I solved it using by making it global variable using `windows.permission_sets = permission_sets ` and re-assigning it in `formState` as `permission_sets=windows.permission_sets`.